# MVC WebAPI Security Access Token how does it validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

---

I am developing a WebAPI with Google Authentication using a JavaScript client.  My question is, once I get the access token and pass it to the web api in the header how does it validate that the access token is legitimate?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the token info end point in Google and pass the obtained access token to get back the use rid, scope, audience or an error message in case the access token is invalid or expired. More details are given in the documentation here.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken

HTH